# Javascript [Beginner]. Call function with object as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code following your comments.
Is inside document ready.

Maybe now is more clear for help me.

I I told you. I need the object "order" outside because I will need it more than once.

Now Ajax is not detecting the object. But when I place it inside the click function all is working fine.

```
var order = { blabla: "blabla", ...}

$('#go_next').click(function() {
  saveStepOne(order);
})

function saveStepOne(order) {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.step-one-val').each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        isValid = false;
        $(this).addClass("has-error");
      }
    });

    if (isValid == false) {
      return false
    } else {
      priceAjaxCall(order)
    }
  }

function priceAjaxCall(order) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "<%=create_order_path%>",
      type: "POST",
      data: { order },
      success: function (data) {
        priceAjaxReturn(data)
      },
      dataType: "json"
    })
    console.log(order)
  }

  function priceAjaxReturn(data){
    if (data["status"] == 200) {
      $(".price").val(data["price"])
    } else {
      $(".price").val("ERROR")
    }
  }
```

Many thanks

Regards

Comment: Is there any other code that modify the "my_obj"? Maybe it get "true" of "false" from elsewhere before the ajax call.

Comment: @BrankVictoria I added more code

Comment: @PolGasullNavarro I am just seeing the same code...

Comment: @BrankVictoria now!

Comment: The thing is, it should work? If you say yes, I will keep trying because maybe is my code. If it's impossible to detect the object outside the click function, what I should do?

Comment: Is all your code inside $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Comment: Also, can you edit your post to know how are you using the console.log() ? According to your code I dont see where you can get the "true" or "false" value

Comment: I edited everything cause your comments. Hope this helps.

Comment: @BrankVictoria now is more clear?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with your code by putting it in the browser console, modify the console.log to "console.log("value of order is: " + JSON.stringify(order))" and calling the function "saveStepOne(order);" I got this in console: "value of order is: {"blabla":"blabla"}" which browser are you using?

Comment: @BrankVictoria Brank I'm with Chrome. Nevermind, don't worry I will try to manage myself, people is downvoting me. Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

it's more specific and give us more idea when you post your code in sendToAjax function.

try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url",
  data: params,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
     $("#resultarea").text(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you please explain what's going on in your code. Please try editing your answer

Comment: this is just a simple api request using the type of POST, as you can see, params(parameters) is the object contains sensitive info/data base on your server side. success is the callback from your api request if the request is successfully handled and return data/result if necessary.

Comment: in addition, you can also check the request response status by doing in error callback:
error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
} else if (jqX.status == 404) {
} else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
} else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
} else if (exception === 'timeout') {
} else if (exception === 'abort') {
} else { console.log('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);}}

Answer (score 0):

@all

After hours thinking I share you the solution. 
If you want to access inside a object from a function you might store this object inside another function and return it.

Example:

```
function myObject() {
 var my_obj = { blabla: "blabla" }
 return my_obj
}

$('.my_class').click(function() {
 variable_name = myObject();
 console.log(variable_name)
 sendToAjaxOrWherverYouWant(variable_name)
}
```

Thank you very much,

Hope this can help someone!

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Hello, but is not an array, is an object. So is working perfectly. Thanks for your time anyway. Please can you upvote me again? ;)

Comment: it still gets overwritten - you never store the var outside the fnc, so each time you call the fnc, it sets the obj to the default values - and I didn't downvote ;) :)

Comment: That's true, but in this case is good for me because if user change inputs, the function will be called and new values entered. Thanks @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Answer (score -1):

try this

sendToAjax(window.my_obj);

Comment: you should always format your code + explain your code ... how is OP going to learn and understand the issue if they're given code that works?